# onkeypress vk_down not working in tcxdateedit

Tags: devexpress, delphi-7

I wanted to code my cxdateedit to show the calendar everytime user hit arrow down on their keyboard and search for datas everytime user hit enter. Therefore, I coded in OnKeyPress events :

```
if (key=chr(VK_RETURN)) then begin
zquery4.Close;
zquery4.SQL.Clear;
zquery4.SQL.Add(sql1);
zquery4.Open;
end;
if key=chr(VK_DOWN) then
cxdateedit1.DroppedDown:=true;
```

While the VK_RETURN (enter key) works perfectly, the one with VK_DOWN (arrow down key) doesn't work at all! Any idea why and how to make it happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys are reserved by the OS for navigation purposes.  A UI control does not receive key events for the arrows unless the control explicitly asks the OS for them, which I'm guessing `cxDateEdit` does not do.  So try subclassing the `cxDateEdit` so you can intercept the [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) message and include the `DLGC_WANTARROWS` flag in the control's response.